# discord.py not finding commands within a class

Tags: discord.py

If I use .join in discord with the code below, I get the following error:

```
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "join" is not found
```

I'm not sure how to fix this (this is turning into being part of a music bot). Here is the relevant code:

```
import discord
import discord.voice_client
from discord import utils
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import *
import discord.utils
import lavalink

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= ".", intents=intents)
    
class MusicCog(commands.Cog):
        def __init__(self, bot):
            self.bot = bot
            self.bot.music = lavalink.Client(self.bot.user.id)
            self.bot.music.add_node('localhost', 7000, 'testing', 'na' , 'music-node')
            self.bot.add_listener(self.bot.music.voice_update_handler, 'on-socket-response')
            self.bot.music.add_event_hook(self.track_hook)
    
        @commands.command(name= 'Join')
        async def join(self, ctx):
            print("join command worked")
            member = utils.find(lambda m: m.id == ctx.author.id, ctx.guild.members)
            if member is not None and member.voice is not None:
                vc = member.voice.channel
                player = self.bot.music.player_manager.create(ctx.guild.id, endpoint= str(ctx.guild.region))
                if not player.is_connected:
                    player.store('channel', ctx.channel.id)
                    await self.connect_to(ctx.guild.id, str(vc.id))
    
    
        @commands.command(name= "Play")
        async def play(self, ctx, *, query):
            try:
                player = self.bot.music.player_manager.get(ctx.guild.id)
                query = f'ytsearch: {query}'
                results = await player.node.get_tracks(query)
                tracks = results['tracks'][0:10]
                i = 0
                query_result = ''
                for track in tracks:
                    i = i + 1
                    query_result = query_result + f'{i}) {track["info"]["title"]} - {track["info"]["url"]}\n'
                show_songs = discord.Embed(
                    title= None,
                    description= None,
                    colour= discord.Colour.blue()
                )
    
                show_songs.description = query_result
    
                await ctx.channel.send(embed= show_songs)
    
                def check(m):
                    return m.author.id == ctx.author.id
    
                response = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
                track = tracks[int(response.conetent)-1]
    
                player.add(requester = ctx.author.id, track = track)
                if not player.is_playing:
                    await player.play()
    
    
            except Exception as error:
                print(error)
    
        async def track_hook(self, event):
            if isinstance(event, lavalink.events.QueueEndEvent):
                guild_id = int(event.player.guild.id)
                await self.connect_to(guild_id, None)
    
        async def connect_to(self, guild_id: int, channel_id: str):
            ws = self.bot._connection._get_websocket(guild_id)
            await ws.voice_state(str(guild_id), channel_id)
    
        def setup(bot):
            bot.add_cog(MusicCog(bot))
```

I've tried changing @commands.command to @bot.command, which didn't end up working, and I'm almost certain the indentation is correct throughout the code, so at this point, I'm not sure how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you have to unindent the setup function.

Comment: I've added that now, but I still get the same error unfortunately

Comment: The name of the command is "Join" not "join".

Answer (score 0):

By default, commands are case sensitive so you'd have to type `.Join` or `.Play` in order to invoke your them.
If you want your commands to be case insensitive, simply type :

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents, case_insensitive=True)
```

PS : the `name` argument in the `commands.command()` decorator refers to what needs to be typed after your prefix to invoke the function.

Comment: I just tried using case_sensntive= True and using .join and .Join, but I still get the same error message (the command .Join is not found)

Comment: Where are you actually running the bot: `bot.run(TOKEN)`?